# Capturing Android soft key events

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I have two edittexts and a button in my layout.When I press the 'done' key in softkeyboard, I need to catch that key event and perform null checking for these edit fields.Can anyone kindly help me on this?

BR,
Rony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {  
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {  
        check for null;
    }
    return(super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));  
}
```

Comment: I think this code only works on hardkey presses, not on the soft keypad.